# AnyLogic - death issue

Tags: anylogic

AnyLogic is so new for me that i'm having issue with aging and death of agents.

Agents are initally created according to a give Age distribution [image]

As time passes they age (I found a nice solutions on the examples available)

I defined a variable "birthTime" as follows
`if( time() == 0 ) {
    return -initialAge;
} else {
    return time();
}`

and a function "age" `return time() - birthTime`

then I have a collection "deathprob" which is an array who stores the daily death prob for every age [image]

for avoiding troubles, I put the last element of the array 1 (if you have 119 you die for sure)

Finally, I have the event "eventDeath" [image]

According to me it should work fine, yet it gives me troubles [image]

I understand that the problem is that someone hasn't died and so it is looking in the array for a position that does not exist...but I need someone to help me...i cannot see the mistake I made... :(

PS "Events" are something that every agents every unit of time (in my case day) do?

. __________ . __________ . ___________ . __________ . __________ . __________ .

this is how I edited the event
[image]

where "onDeath()" is just the following function `main.remove_individuals(this);`

I'm not getting anymore the problem before...I just want to make sure I got this rigth..is the condition of this event checked by every agent every unit of time?

Thanks!

Comment: It seems that there is no error in your calculations, you just need to add more 1 to the collection 'deathprob' to avoid troubles for agents in age > 119.

Comment: In case of a condition triggered event, the condition specified in the properties of the event is not checked every unit of time, but checked when an event occurs inside the agent (e.g. a transition is triggered) or 'onChange()' function is called for this agent (e.g. people.get(i).onChange())

Comment: Thanks for your tip! I think I got the problem...I want every agent to check the condition every unit of time (agent can die any day) and not just when they change state inside the statechart... :)  I edited the question with the new event...is this cheked every unit of time by every agent? @TatianaGomzina thanks!

Comment: Be assured that the condition 'bernoulli(p) == 1 is checked every day for each agent from the population 'individuals' now

Comment: However, I guess, the problem may happen again if some agent turns 120

Comment: The problem should not happen again because I put p = 1 if you are 119, so that the condition "bernoulli (p) == 1" is satisfied for sure...I just don't get how in AnyLogic I can check whether the condition is checked by every agent every day...however I am not having issues any more for now :)

Comment: The error occurs, since there are no p = 1 in the collection 'deathprob' for agents older than 119.

Comment: The event is put into an agent type and cyclic, therefore it is triggered inside every agent of this agent type periodically according to recurrence time (every day in your case)